# HTML Classes WITH IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax

I'm a little confused about HTML classes and IDs, as I'd like to use them BOTH to describe an HTML element. Is this valid and supported by most browsers?

The motivation for me to use both is this:

1. I have a CSS style that I would like applied to multiple elements.
2. I have some AJAX and Javascript that will manipulate those same elements, so I need a way to identify which element is which using an ID.
3. So I'd like to use an id to identify each element for JS manipulation AND at the same time I would like to specify a class so that the same style is applied from the same css.

Comment: @John Topley: It should be "ids": it's short for "identifier," it's not an initialism or acronym.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An ID would be unique to only one item, where a class can be used to group many items together.  You can use them together as you stated, ID as a unique identifier for Javascript and the class to markup with CSS.

Search for [html class vs id](http://www.google.com/search?q=html+classes+vs+id) to get many articles about this topic.

Example:

```
<ul>
    <li class="odd" id="item1">First Item in the List</li>
    <li class="even" id="item2">Second Item in the List</li>
    <li class="odd" id="item3">Third Item in the List</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is perfectly valid to use both the ID and Class properties in one element. Example:

```
<div class="infoBox" id="myUniqueStyle"> *content* </div>
```

Still, keep in mind that an ID can only be used once (hence its name), while you can use classes as many times as you'd like througout a document. You can still use both the ID and the class to apply styles, while only the ID is a simple way of reaching the element through javascript.

A good way of doing it is applying IDs to all elements that you know are unique (header, navigation, main containers etc.), and classes to everything else.

"Is *the*" applies to elements using ID: "This *is the* navigation bar", "this *is the* header"

"Is *a*" or "is *an*" applies to elements using classes: "This *is a* blogPost", "this *is an* infoBox" etc.

Comment: It's strange that everyone got through this without ever using the word: selector.

Comment: That's because there is no selector in HTML. We're not discussing the stylesheet setup here, but the markup :)

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely use both if you need to.

An ID is typically used to identify structural sections of your site - you should have only **one** element with a particular ID and any element can have only one ID.

A class is used to set styles which might be used in more than one place in your HTML file - any element can have multiple classes set.

A typical HTML document using both IDs and classes might be something like

```
<html>
...
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<ul id="nav" class="full-width dark">...</ul>
<div id="content">
<div id="important-container" class="class-set-by-javascript another-class-set-by-javascript"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any normal browser should allow the setting of CSS classes regardless of element id. However, setting styles on a specific element (using ids, for example) may override styles set through a CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

Just a very obscure note about combining class and id in your CSS declarations, there's a bug with IE6, if you have:

- two or more pages which have an
  element with the same `id`
- those elements have different
  `class`es
- you're styling them using an
  `#idname.classname` rule

then only the first rule in the stylesheet will take effect.

See [this page](http://sonspring.com/index.php?id=102) for details

Answer (score -3):

Yes it is valid in all browsers. ID expresses just the unique IDentification of your html control through others, and class applies some style to it. Use IDs when there is only one occurence per page. Use classes when there are one or more occurences per page.

Comment: Because your answer is wrong.  As stated below, ID's are used for unique elements.  Classes are used for multiple elements.  Both are used for style.

Comment: oh come on man! the question was :Is this valid and supported by most browsers? And that was only the answer to that! anyway

Comment: Your answer is not only incorrect, it doesn't even make sense as a sentence. Both class and id are used to identify parts of the HTML. What does "identification of your html control through others" mean?

Comment: the answer is correct, and the sentence too. ambrose go and take some english grammar course.

Comment: Class has nothing special to do with style. The answer also implies that they are or should be mutually exclusive.

Comment: he edited his answer to be correct, although it could still be better. SQLMaster ... kinda mean